# Windows phone frame by frame animation

Tags: windows-phone-8, after-effects

I create an animation with Adobe After Effects. I want to use this animation in my Windows Phone 8.1 app. I crate the png sequence from Adobe. How can I use this animation in Windows Phone Applcation.

Comment: Are you going to apply this animation to any of your controls? If you're heading into animation it would be better if you go with Blend.

Comment: No this animation start at the beggining and it will never stop like a video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create frame by frame animation with Expression Blend.
Link: [Create a simple animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc294948(v=expression.40).aspx)

Edit:
I tried to change Image Source in timeline recording. For some reason, when I change the Source, Blend applies it to actual Image instead of adding it as a part of Storyboard.

I can do it with XAML though. See if you can use this:

Say your Image is defined like this:

```
<Image x:Name="myImg"/>
```

Then you can define StoryBoard like this:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myImg"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="/Assets/image1.png"/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="/Assets/image2.png"/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="/Assets/image3.png"/>  
                            ..........  
                            ..........  
                            ..........  
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
```

The KeyTime is specified as hour:min:sec. You can also specify miliseconds, like 0:0:0.100

Comment: How can I change source of Image in blend time dependently

Comment: I was unable to do that with Blend. Please check my modified answer.

Comment: It works perfectly but there ara some balnking some frames. How can I prevent this blinkings

Comment: You might try increasing the frequency of KeyFrames to get some smoothness (ie add more KeyFrame). If Source were a continuous value like Opacity, you could get smoother transitions by using DoubleAnimation. In this case it simply changes to specified Value at specified KeyTime.